# Почему в базу данных заносится не то число которое отправляю

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть поле с номером я вожу номер например(87070000707)если в контролере проверить то он такой же как и вводил но в бд падает совсем другое число(2147483647)
почему так происходит прошу помочь

***контроллер***

```
$dopysk = new Dopysk();
$dopysk->number = $request->number;
 $dopysk->save();
```

> в бд нет никакого значения по умолчанию но если ввести число по меньше
>   то все работает и заносится все правильно

Comment: Какой тип данных у поля куда пишите? Судя по всему вы превышаете лимит целого числа и пишется в итоге максимально возможное значение если вводимое число больше. Либо используйте более широкий числовой тип данных, либо делайте строковый тип.

Answer (score 3):

Прочитайте про тип `int` в [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) документации, это максимальное значение для `int`.
[image: Required Storage and Range for Integer Types Supported by MySQL]
 Вам нужно сменить тип `int` на `bigint`:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname BIGINT;
```

Если и этого лимита не хватит, то думаю стоит сменить тип на строку.